# ARC latest update (9.10.0.21) problem with fix

Tags: advantage-database-server

I have just installed 9.10.0.21 and the fix for "Fixed an issue where ARC would show up off the visible desktop if previously opened on a screen that was no longer attached." now opens ARC on monitor number 1 every time.

It used to open it on whichever monitor I last used.  I realise this is an easy way to fix a problem if you close it on monitor number 2 then try to open it with if that monitor is no longer attached, but it's a pain.

Surely the number of instances of people opening ARC with a different screen configuration is much smaller than the number of instances being the same as last time, so more people will be affected by this change than it will have solved a problem for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are seeing is the intended behavior. If the screen ARC was last opened on is available, it will open there (just like it used to). If the screen is not available, it will open on screen 1. I just verified this with my installation. If you are seeing some other behavior can you send an email describing your setup to advantage@ianywhere.com?  Thanks!

Comment: This was indeed a bug, and was fixed in 9.10.0.23 available at http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=13&Product=8&Platform=6

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.  I have sent an email.
Just to let everyone who reads this know, it only happens if ARC was closed when it was maximized on screen 2, non-maximized will reopen on screen 2, but maximized opens on screen 1.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, I verified this behavior (after the clarification about the window's maximized state) and will fix it.

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback Gareth. We are releasing a fix to address a couple of regression bugs in ARC, including this one. Watch for it this week.